# ffmpeg: video track is shorter than audio track - how to pad the video track so their lengths match?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp4 file where the video track is 1 minute shorter than the audio track. I would like to pad the video track with anything, preferably just black frames, so both lengths match and the file plays properly - most video players get confused with this file and can't seek after the video track ends. Any kind of padding is appropriate, even looping the video track, as long as the file is fixed.

Comment: You can use -shortest and it will cut the part of the sound of after the video is over....

Comment: I want to pad the video and keep the entire audio.

Comment: You can use [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) filter : `-vf tpad=stop_duration=60` to add 60s of black frames at the end of video stream.